# Can FDT deal with .fla files or not?

Tags: windows, flash, ide

I'm trying to find an all-in-one IDE for flash, one that can deal with various flash related files.

I just read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385169/best-ide-for-actionscript-3-coding) and it recommends [fdt](http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/), but seems `fdt` can only deal with scripts but not `.fla` ones.

Which IDE should I use so that I can use it to develop various files involved in flash developing?

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain it can not. Is there any particular reason you need this? Most developers code in external .as files. This way code is in one location and not buried in the timeline. Also the code can be placed in source control.

For an all in one solution, Adobe Flash CS5 is probably your best bet. They have somewhat improved the IDE and added things like autocomplete.

Comment: With `.fla` the related resources(scripts,images,layers etc..) are automatically grouped together,that's why I prefer `.fla`

Answer (score 0):

Flash Builder 4 and Adobe Flash CS5 have finally solved this problem - you can now create an FLA in Flash and then use the wizard to easily create a Flash Builder project around the .fla. All of your classes have access to library exports etc, and you can set it up so that when you click to edit a Class file in Flash it automatically opens the file in Flash Builder.

I really like it.

Comment: so are you saying that it will kinda convert your .fla to flash builder format (as if you had used flash builder to begin with)? if so thats pretty cool.

Comment: No, it doesn't convert it per se - Flash Builder just has a new project type, ".fla project" or somesuch. You create your .fla then create a flash builder project using their wizard. You tell it where your .fla is and them bam, you're all set. Your changes in either one automatically get reflected in both. It's pretty slick.